Square in a square

I have to show that $BE=DG$, which is easy, and that $BE$ and $DG$ are perpendicular, and here is the problem. $ABCD$ and $AEFG$ are two squares.
I only manage to find a solution using a ($360^\circ-\angle BAE$) rotation
(trigonometric way), but a simpler solution I can't see.

My solution is ok? Using that rotation, $B$, $A$, $E$ and $D$, $A$, $G$ will be colinear, therefore perpendicular.
Is there a simpler solution?
Thanks.


You've got a step by step solution below. But your stated solution is already totally adequate if you're OK with using transformations, which makes the proofs nearly immediate: Proof 1: $\triangle{AEB} \cong \triangle{AGD}$ and map to each other by a quarter turn on $A$; Proof 2: $AEFG$ maps to $ABCD$ by a quarter-turn on $A$ and dilation $\frac{AE}{AB}$.

$AE=AG$ , (sides of square $AEFG$)
$\angle EAB = \angle DAG$ ,   ($\angle EAB + \angle EAD = \angle EAB + \angle DAG = 90^{\circ}$)
$AB=AD$ , (sides of square $ABCD$)
$\triangle AEB \cong \triangle ADG$ , (S.A.S Congruency Theorem)
Therefore $BE=DG$

Let extension of $AE$ intersect $DG$ at $M$
Since $\angle B =\angle D$ and $\angle N_1 =\angle N_2$, $\angle M =\angle A =90^{\circ}$ and $BE\perp DG$

That was the easy part, according to the OP.

Yeah, that I saw it too, told you. Thx a lot.

@TonyK : I completed the solution

@Numbers : I completed the solution

Yes, your method is very good, rotating $\triangle BAE$ counterclockwise by $90^{\circ}$.
@Lion Heart showed $\triangle AEB \cong \triangle ADG$, and concluded $BE=DG$. In order to show $BE\perp DG$, extend $BE$ to intersect $DG$ at $K$. From $\triangle AEB \cong \triangle ADG$, we have $\angle EBA=\angle ADG$ (marked by green). Now note that sum of the angles in the quadrilateral $KDCB$ is $360^{\circ}$  and $\angle KDA+\angle CBK= 90^{\circ}$, hence $\angle BKD=360^{\circ}-(3\times90^{\circ})=90^{\circ}$.


Ohh, this is beautiful, thx.

Extend $BE$ to intersect $DG$ at point $H$ and $AD$ at point $I$.
$BE \bot DG$ if $\angle BHD = 90°$.
$BC \parallel AD$ (I trust you need no proof of this), so $\angle CBE = \angle CBH = \angle DIH$.
$\triangle ABE \cong \triangle ADG$, so $\angle ABE = \angle ADG$.
$\angle ABE + \angle CBE = 90°$, so $\angle ADG + \angle DIH = 90°$.
Given that the sum of internal angles in a triangle is always $180°$, $\angle BHD = \angle IHD = 90°$.
We have therefore shown that $BE \bot DG$.

In this image, the red and green angles are our two (pairs of) angles summing to $90°$.
